# Empty schema specified for the load job - Load CSV

Tags: python-3.x, google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage, airflow

I'm trying to load a CSV file, from Google Cloud Storage, into an empty Google Big Query table, through a GoogleCloudStorageToBigQueryOperator task.

```
t8 = GoogleCloudStorageToBigQueryOperator(
    task_id='gcs_send_dim_report',
    bucket='report',
    source_objects=[
        'gs://report/test-dim-report/dim_report_{{ ds_nodash }}.csv'
    ],
    schema_fields=['filename_pdf','filename_png', 'week_date', 'code'],
    skip_leading_rows=1,
    source_format = 'CSV',
    create_disposition='CREATE_IF_NEEDED',
    write_disposition='WRITE_TRUNCATE',
    destination_project_dataset_table='xxxx-yyyy:report.test_dim_report_{{ ds_nodash }}',
    dag=dag
)
```

The table to be loaded already has schema defined in Big Query, even so, to face this error, I added the parameter `schema_fields` with the columns of the CSV that I am using. Looking at the task log, I first encounter the following dependency errors:

```
from google.appengine.api import memcache
[2018-06-22 05:58:49,650] {base_task_runner.py:98} INFO - Subtask: ImportError: No module named 'google.appengine'
[2018-06-22 05:58:49,650] {base_task_runner.py:98} INFO - Subtask: 
[2018-06-22 05:58:49,651] {base_task_runner.py:98} INFO - Subtask: During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
[2018-06-22 05:58:49,651] {base_task_runner.py:98} INFO - Subtask: 
[2018-06-22 05:58:49,651] {base_task_runner.py:98} INFO - Subtask: Traceback (most recent call last):
[2018-06-22 05:58:49,652] {base_task_runner.py:98} INFO - Subtask:   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/googleapiclient/discovery_cache/file_cache.py", line 33, in <module>
[2018-06-22 05:58:49,652] {base_task_runner.py:98} INFO - Subtask:     from oauth2client.contrib.locked_file import LockedFile
[2018-06-22 05:58:49,652] {base_task_runner.py:98} INFO - Subtask: ImportError: No module named 'oauth2client.contrib.locked_file'
```

At the end of the log, the final error is displayed:

```
Exception: BigQuery job failed. Final error was: {'reason': 'invalid', 'message': 'Empty schema specified for the load job. Please specify a schema that describes the data being loaded.'}.
```

I'm looking for some workaroud for that error, in order to successfully load my CSV file into Google Big Query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Twoways to achieve this. This is all from the code documentation, also this initial bit:

> The schema to be used for the BigQuery table may be specified in one of
>       two ways. You may either directly pass the schema fields in, or you may
>       point the operator to a Google cloud storage object name. The object in
>       Google cloud storage must be a JSON file with the schema fields in it.

- Correctly define `schema_fields` as seen in the documentation for `GoogleCloudStorageToBigQueryOperator`. An example how to define a schema can be found here: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/schemas

> If set, the schema field list as defined here:
>           https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/jobs#configuration.load
>           Should not be set when source_format is 'DATASTORE_BACKUP'.

Example (from example link):

```
schema = [
    bigquery.SchemaField('full_name', 'STRING', mode='REQUIRED'),
    bigquery.SchemaField('age', 'INTEGER', mode='REQUIRED'),
]
```

- Set `schema_object`.

> If set, a GCS object path pointing to a .json file that
>           contains the schema for the table. (templated)

Comment: The `schema_fields` option you note does not work. It gives this error.

```ERROR - Object of type 'SchemaField' is not JSON serializable```

Comment: Additionally, the `schema_object` option you specify doesn't exactly work that way either.  

It seems that the the source files and the `schema_object` file must both be in the `bucket` you specify, additionally, when you reference those objects, they have to be relative to the bucket, not the full `gs://` URI.

Comment: @dboshardy If it does not work for you, I suggest asking a new question. Since there is no further information in how you use GCS or any example code, it is impossible to help you.

Answer (score 1):

As noted by [@dboshardy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3037697/dboshardy), the answer provided by [@tobi6](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5191221/tobi6) results in the following error:

> ERROR - Object of type 'SchemaField' is not JSON serializable

As the error sugests, SchemaField is not a JSON serializable class, whereas the parameter schema_fields expects a JSON serializable object.

The solution is to pass the schema as a list of dictionaries, as per the Airflow documentation: https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/_api/airflow/contrib/operators/bigquery_operator/index.html#airflow.contrib.operators.bigquery_operator.BigQueryCreateEmptyTableOperator

Example (based on OP question):

```
schema = [
    {"name": "filename_pdf", "type": "STRING", "mode": "REQUIRED"},
    {"name": "filename_png", "type": "STRING", "mode": "REQUIRED"},
    {"name": "week_date", "type": "DATE", "mode": "REQUIRED"},
    {"name": "code", "type": "INTEGER", "mode": "NULLABLE"}
]
```

The solution provided was successfully tested through Google  Cloud Composer (airflow v1.10.6) for a similar problem.